# How do I include/link a DLL while using Visual C++ 2010 command prompt

Tags: windows, api, visual-c++, dll

I am trying to compile a DLL in VC++ 2010 command prompt, and one of the functions I am using is in urlmon.dll.  How do I link this DLL to my source file?  (It's only one .cpp file).  I tried putting the dll in the same folder.  Do I need the lib file instead?

Currently I'm just running:
cl -LD filename

I've tried googling, but I have had no success. Thanks for those who looked.

Comment: Use a project template to get this right.  Add "urlmon.lib" to the linker's Input + Additional Dependencies setting.

Comment: @Hans: Using an IDE won't make this any easier.  He just needs the .lib file instead, as the question already speculated.

Comment: Hmya, let's keep that link command a secret.

Answer (score 1):

You must link with the import library urlmon.lib.  It's impossible to link directly to a DLL.  (The only other way to get functions out of a DLL, in the absence of an "import library" for that DLL, is to use functions like LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to find, load, and extract the particular function you want.)

Answer (score 1):

Put this line into your source file:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon")
```

Your source file already is using the urlmon functions, so it makes sense to list the library right alongside.